# What is referenceId in Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g

We create some column named referenceId but when we do a simple select on this column we must to add double quote. If we don't specify double quote with have an invalid identifier exception from Oracle database. Why?

I see this post [which has the same problem](https://community.oracle.com/thread/370354). But no response.

In order to correct this we must to generate the column in upper case. (In fact when we have create the column we use double quote on column name)

What is referenceId? Is it a Oracle keyword?

Comment: Please show the table definition and select statement, and complete error message.

Comment: When you created it as a quoted identifier, what case was the name? You make it sound like it was `"REFERENCEID"` which would allow you to query it unquoted. So yes, please show the table creation statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not a keyword. You did not mention which tool you used to create that column. I think this is most important to mention. Oracle object names are case-sensitive - sometimes. They are case sensitive when used in double quotes - otherwise the case does not matter.

So:

```
alter table add column test number; -- will add column named TEST
alter table add column TEST number; -- will add column named TEST
alter table add column "Test" number; -- will add column named Test
```

So the 3rd one column name is case-sensitive and must use double-quotes whenever referenced. The column name "TEST" is then different from "Test".

PS: Using case-sensitive object names can lead to various problems. Avoid it.

Comment: Ok we use Liquibase in order to generate schema. You are right. We have set objectQuotingStrategy to QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS we change now to QUOTE_ONLY_RESERVED_WORDS. But I'm surprised of Oracle's behaviour

Comment: The reason behind is simple. Backward compatibility. At first Oracle's SQL was case in-sensitive and everything was converted to uppercase in background. Then they added double-quoted identifiers, and these are case sensitive.